# How to store Facebook user ID for authorization?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook api to let my users login/signup
and if they don't have an account they create a new one, of if they already have an account they can connect the older with FB.

I did this for few years but recently i noticed my login button doesn;t work anymore, becays ei think they changed the users Id. is that correct?

what value should I store to be sure that user has a FB account and is the same user.

is the app_scoped_user_id good? are they gonna change again the ID?

Comment: We have not changed any ids. You can just use the normal id

Comment: _If_ ids have changed, then most likely because you have changed app ids. With a different app, you would get a different app-scoped user id. As long as you use the same app, the app-scoped user id will not change.

Comment: ohh.... yes i'm using a new app...